# MVC Return Partial View as JSON

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

Is there a way to return an HTML string from rendering a partial as part of a JSON response from MVC?

```
    public ActionResult ReturnSpecialJsonIfInvalid(AwesomenessModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(Request.IsAjaxRequest()
                return PartialView("NotEvil", model);
            return View(model)
        }
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return Json(new { error=true, message = PartialView("Evil",model)});
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You can extract the html string from the PartialViewResult object, similar to the answer to this thread:

[Render a view as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/483091/render-a-view-as-a-string)

PartialViewResult and ViewResult both derive from ViewResultBase, so the same method should work on both.

Using the code from the thread above, you would be able to use:

```
public ActionResult ReturnSpecialJsonIfInvalid(AwesomenessModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            return PartialView("NotEvil", model);
        return View(model)
    }
    if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return Json(new { error = true, message = RenderViewToString(PartialView("Evil", model))});
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: if it would be an ajax call calling ReturnSpecialJsonIfInvalid, i believe it is expected to something with data returned. how would jquery differentiate view from json?

Comment: Where is the definition of RenderViewToString() method?

Comment: @Sinjai there is not `RenderViewToString` method with `PartialViewResult` parameter. But there are similar other methods. Inserting the method here would be useful.

Comment: how to pass an object of collection, ie ToList() or AsQueryable() object ?

Comment: can you write the method RenderViewToString? I need something like this I can not find it. Thanks

Answer (score 35):

Instead of `RenderViewToString` I prefer a approach like

```
return Json(new { Url = Url.Action("Evil", model) });
```

then you can catch the result in your javascript and do something like

```
success: function(data) {
    $.post(data.Url, function(partial) { 
        $('#IdOfDivToUpdate').html(partial);
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice approach. Cleaner then rendering view to string.

Comment: But it needs more http requests.

Comment: But this leaves out the 'error' field in the json response.

Comment: The `Url.Action("Evil", model)` will generate a get query string but your ajax method is post and it will throw error status of 500(Internal Server Error).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(function () {
        $("select#ExamID").change(function (evt) {

            var classid = $('#ClassId').val();
            var StudentId = $('#StudentId').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/StudentMarks/ShowStudentSubjects",
                type: 'POST',
                data: { classId: classid, StudentId: StudentId, ExamID: $(this).val() },
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#ShowStudentSubjects').html(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr) { alert("Something seems Wrong"); }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).