# MVC 4 Html Partial Render as Encoded HTML string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How would I get this:

```
<code class="language-markup">@Html.Partial("components")</code>
```

To output the encoded version of the HTML markup? I tried the httpUtility but it threw up a few errors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json

Comment: Put Error too, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think just call the encode

```
<code class="language-markup">
    @Html.Encode(Html.Partial("components"))
</code>
```

Comment: while this works in ASP.NET MVC, unfortunately, this one does not work with ASP.NET Core 2.x