# How to return View with JSON result

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Is there any way to return the View("controller", model) with JSON result? I've done like this(see code below) but it returns me an error.

```
    if (thereserror == true)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            view = RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "Index", model),
            isValid = false,
            description = "Error!",
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        });
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            view = RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "Index", model),
            isValid = true,
            description = "Hey!",
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        });
    }

    private static string RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ViewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            var ViewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, ViewResult.View, controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
            ViewResult.View.Render(ViewContext, sw);
            ViewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, ViewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

For my AJAX I'm doing like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/serviceentry/getservice",
        data: ({ "SONumber": soNumber }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.isValid) {
                //I don't know what to put here
            };
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

I saw something like this but I don't know what to do: [MVC Return Partial View as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json)

Comment: You just need to redirect to specific view after you get data from ajax is this you want ?

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the partial view? To include it in the DOM you might do say `$(someElement).html(data.view);`

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: Note you have the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in the wrong place - its `return Json(new { view = ..., description = "Hey!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for correcting me. Actually that's one of my error. Allow Get using JsonRequestBehavior. But my concern is that, in my controller I can retrieved data from my dataset and put it in my **Model**. I want it to return just like this behavior **return View("Index", model)**

Comment: So what problem are you having? And you still have not stated what your want to do with the partial view you returned

Comment: @StephenMuecke I just want to return View and data (json result) at the same time. Just like this one [link](https://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/mvc-jsonresult-returning-view-and-data-at-the-same-time)

Comment: I know. But what is your problem!

Comment: @StephenMuecke. I change the **if** logic. I think I got it now. I just want to return JSON result with "error" description. What I did was.


            `if (!isError)
            {
                return View("Index", model);
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    view = RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "Index", model),
                    isValid = false,
                    description = errResult
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON` you are returning contains 4 properties, the way you are accessing `isValid`, similarly access the `View`.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/serviceentry/getservice",
        data: ({ "SONumber": soNumber }),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.isValid) {
                //Element- Where you want to show the partialView
                $(Element).html(data.view)
            };
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
```

PS: Also Pointing the wrong placement of `JSONRequestBehavior`.

```
if (thereserror == true)
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            view = RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "Index", model),
            isValid = false,
            description = "Error!"
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(new
        {
            view = RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext, "Index", model),
            isValid = true,
            description = "Hey!"
        },JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    private static string RenderRazorViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, object model)
    {
        controllerContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        using (var sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            var ViewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controllerContext, viewName);
            var ViewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, ViewResult.View, controllerContext.Controller.ViewData, controllerContext.Controller.TempData, sw);
            ViewResult.View.Render(ViewContext, sw);
            ViewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(controllerContext, ViewResult.View);
            return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to return the whole page with model value not just the element?

Comment: Since you are using AJAX here, its better that you return JSON data. You just have toinclude html(view) as one of the property in your json data.

Comment: @Zach Yes, It's possible. You can return your html with model. Create a partial view and return the partial view with model instead of json result.

Comment: @JibinBalachandran OP needs other properties like `isValid` , `description`(used in ajax success part). So returning just the html wont serve his cause.