# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC return partial view using Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, asp.net-core-6.0

I am writing an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application.

I have a method in a controller that I need to retrieve a Json value like this

a boolean and a Partial View with the model class

```
return Json(new { success = true, PartialView("SearchResult", resultViewModel) });
```

I found this article that says to retrieve PartialView as string. [here][1]

like this

```
return Json(new { error = true, message = RenderViewToString(PartialView("Evil", model))});
```

I dont have `RenderViewToString` function. Searching.. I found this

```
protected string RenderViewAsString( string viewName, object model)
        {
            viewName = viewName ?? ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                IView view = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, true).View;
                if(view!=null)
                { 
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, ViewData, TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
                    view.RenderAsync(viewContext).Wait();
                }
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

From Jquery I have this

```
  success: function (result) {
                        $("#dvBody").html(result.url);
                    },
```

the problem is that it returns a `View` instead of a `PartialView`

Is there a way I can make it return a PartialView?

thanks
[1]: [MVC Return Partial View as JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730777/mvc-return-partial-view-as-json)

Comment: You better include in your question an explanation what are you trying to reach? Why do you have to return partial view as a string when there are much better  and easier ways?

Comment: HI, I said I want to render a Partial View, but it is render as a View instead... thanks

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that it returns a View instead of a PartialView

Try to add below in your PartialView:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

result:
[image]

My demo like below:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Details(string customerId)
        {
            Phone phone = GetCustomers().Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(customerId)).FirstOrDefault().Phone;
            PartialViewResult partialViewResult = PartialView("_Phone", phone);
           
            string viewContent = RenderViewToString("_Phone", phone);

            return Json(new { PartialView = viewContent });
        }
```

ajax success function:

```
success: function (response) {                       
                        $('#dialog').append('<p>' + response.partialView + '</p>');
                    }
```

Comment: HI Still it is render as View and not as Partial View. I think the problem is the function RenderViewToString... you are using the same I posted? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Diego , I try the both method and they  render as Partial View. look:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mazp.gif    Do you add `Layout = null;` in the Partial View?

Comment: @Diego I see you "From Jquery I have this: $("#dvBody").html(result.url);" What's your  `return Json()`? Can you try `return Json(new { PartialView = viewContent });` like my code?

Answer (score 0):

I replace this function

```
protected string RenderViewAsString( string viewName, object model)
        {
            viewName = viewName ?? ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            ViewData.Model = model;

            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                IView view = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, true).View;
                if(view!=null)
                { 
                    ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, view, ViewData, TempData, sw, new HtmlHelperOptions());
                    view.RenderAsync(viewContext).Wait();
                }
                return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

for this one

```
 public string ConvertViewToString(ControllerContext controllerContext, PartialViewResult pvr, ICompositeViewEngine _viewEngine)
        {
            using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                ViewEngineResult vResult = _viewEngine.FindView(controllerContext, pvr.ViewName, false);
                ViewContext viewContext = new ViewContext(controllerContext, vResult.View, pvr.ViewData, pvr.TempData, writer, new HtmlHelperOptions());

                vResult.View.RenderAsync(viewContext);

                return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
            }
        }
```

I think there is problem in this line

```
IView view = _viewEngine.FindView(ControllerContext, viewName, true).View;
```